# iPad landscape UIImagePickerController weird black rectangle

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape

I have an iPad app that works only in landscape mode and everything works great. I have a problem when I try to launch the Photos Gallery in landscape... after reading all these posts it seems it is not possible. Let's assume that... I still try to display it, it goes nice into portrait, but I have a weird rectangle in the upper right corner that it shouldn't be there. Do you have any idea why is there or have you encountered something similar?

My code is the following:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum; 

    picker.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPageSheet;

    [self presentModalViewController: picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
```

[image: Photo gallery in portrait with weird rectangle]

Comment: please print NSLog(@"subviews on picker : %@",[picker.view subview]); , it can reveal the mystry.

Comment: I have decided to display it inside a popup view controller and works just fine... i really don't have any idea on why it acted so weird